# If a Contact is Created in AD, Will that Cause the Creation of a Contact in Exchange?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365, exchange-hybrid

If a contact is created in the AD, will it automatically be created in Exchange as well?

Windows Server 2008 R2 environment
On-premise Exchange 2010 hybrid with O365
Exchange is on secondary DC
AD change is happening on primary DC

To simplify contact creation and management, I'd like to script the creation of a contact in the Contacts OU in AD and not directly in Exchange. I'm pretty sure that the contact will be replicated in Exchange from the AD, but I haven't found documentation either way.

I have created a test contact in the AD and am currently waiting to see what happens.

Comment: It won't. Exchange email contacts are different and behave differently than plain AD contacts. You can email-enable the "normal" contacts by using PowerShell and something like this: `get-contact` and `enable-mailcontact`.

Answer (score 3):

No, creating an AD contact does not automatically create an Exchange contact. You should be able to script both processes, though.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, it would not automatically create Exchange contact if only create object in AD.

But if you create mail contact in Exchange, it would automatically create contact object in AD.